# Putting data from a JSON request into the page with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I used [this tutorial](http://www.dynamicguru.com/jquery/get-weather-info-free-api-jquery-ajax/) to consume a weather service. It works; however, it returns the data in console.log because I don't know how to write it to the page.

Here is my code

```
<script>
    function getWeatherFunction() {
        var my_city = $('#zip').valueOf;
        if (my_city == null) {
            alert('Put in a zip code')
        }
        var my_key = "772bc01c638bb23d13e33940a8454";
        var no_of_days = 2;


        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: 'true',
            url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=" + my_city + "&key=" + my_key + "&format=json&no_of_days=" + no_of_days + "&includeLocation=yes",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Here is the data", data);
                alert("Here is the data" + data.toSource());
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data");
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

This gives an an output like this
[image: JSON Output]

How can I write this data to the page? Or how can i pull out specific parts of this data?

Comment: That function returns an ```data``` as an object. You can do whatever you wish with that data in the ```success``` part of the code. Currently, it's displaying it in the console log.

Comment: Right. I get that. But its currently doing that because I dont know what else I can do with it. I don't know how to have it so that it puts the code on my page.

Comment: You should look at any number of data binding frameworks that will let you take data and bind it to html on your page. There are lots of them out there, knockout and angular to name two.

Comment: Ok i will. I wasnt sure if there was a really simple way to do this and I just didnt know about it. I will look into those two.

Comment: To use be able to utilize the data fully, you have to understand how the data is stored in the object. For example, to get the current temperature of the location you passed into the function, you'd use this code ```data.data.current_condition[0].temp_C``` You can set that to a variable and use it just like any other variables in JS. I suggest expanding the object in the inspector to get a better idea of its structure.

Comment: @Narong that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

W3Schools has a pretty nice primer on how to work with JSON data in javascript which can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_eval.asp)

Really the jist of it is that you have an object which you will need to access and then do something with the data, in your case, putting it on the page.

A very very simple way to do this would be to create a div on your page with a specific id, like so:

```
<div id="weatherInformationDiv">
</div>
```

And then use jquery's html function to directly inject it into the div (reference on jquery html function [here](https://api.jquery.com/html/)), with a function, like so:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            crossDomain: 'true',
            url: "http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v2/weather.ashx?q=" + my_city + "&key=" + my_key + "&format=json&no_of_days=" + no_of_days + "&includeLocation=yes",
            success: function (data) {
                //console.log("Here is the data", data);
                $('#weatherInformationDiv').html(data);
                alert("Here is the data" + data.toSource());
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data");
            }
        });
```

This will dump the raw returned JSON data into a div on your page and should hopefully get you started.

Comment: This seems right, but doesnt actually do anything. I'm not sure why

Comment: You were missing a zip code I added one for new york, and the actual call to the function, I added one, you will need to parse the json to get human readable results but you are getting a json result now (http://jsfiddle.net/c3d5gfpk/)